# Convert Python to PHP

Tags: php, python

I tried to convert a script in Python to PHP. It didn't work.

```
def getL5(iValue,Pvalue):
PixelNoise = open(Pvalue + '.txt','r')
l5 = {}
Ivalue = int(iValue) % 10000
p_x = Ivalue % 100
p_y = int(math.floor(Ivalue / 100))
for iValue in PixelNoise:
    pixel,value = iValue.strip().split(':')
    l5[pixel] = value
PixelNoise.close()
return l5[str(p_x)+','+str(p_y)]
```

The above is the Python.

```
public function getL5($iValue,$Pvalue) {
$PixelNoise = fopen($Pvalue.'.txt', "r");
$L5 = array();
$Ivalue = intval ($iValue) % 10000;
$p_x = $Ivalue % 100;
$p_y = intval(floor($Ivalue / 100));
foreach ($PixelNoise as $iValue){
    $temp= explode(':', $iValue);
    $pixel=$temp[0];
    $value=$temp[1];
    $L5[$pixel] = $value;
}
fclose($PixelNoise);
return $L5[(string)$p_x.','.(string)$p_y];
}
```

The above is my PHP code. Where is it wrong?

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Notice there is a `strip` in python you are not doing in PHP.  Don't know if that's causing the problem though, because you don't say what the symptoms are.  Do you honestly think that"don't work" is helpful diagnostics?

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot foreach through lines of a file.  One popular option is to use a while loop with fgets.

```
function getL5($iValue,$Pvalue) {
   $PixelNoise = fopen($Pvalue.'.txt', "r");
   $L5 = array();
   $Ivalue = intval ($iValue) % 10000;
   $p_x = $Ivalue % 100;
   $p_y = intval(floor($Ivalue / 100));
   if ($PixelNoise) {
       while ($iValue = fgets($PixelNoise)) {
           $temp= explode(':', trim($iValue));
           $pixel=$temp[0];
           $value=$temp[1];
           $L5[$pixel] = $value;
       }
       fclose($PixelNoise);
   }
   else {
     print "There was an error opening the file.";
     // You might want to do some error handling here
     // e.g. trigger an error, or make this function return false.
   }
   return $L5[(string)$p_x.','.(string)$p_y];
```

}

For consistency you can also use strval() just like intval() instead of the casting.    Also FYI the coding style is not one PHP developers will enjoy reading, consider [perusing this advice](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).